# Acquiring Method data from smart contract (using Etherscan API)

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, method

I managed to make API calls for "Normal Transactions" by address. But I'm missing 2nd column from the results which is "Method".

When I use "export csv" method on the website it includes methods but my API call doesn't include it.

Can anyone help me solve this?